# WebRTC Connection State management

Tags: webrtc

What I wish to achieve:

1. When establish a connection, prevent user from sending any message until the connection had finished all the setup (with STUN/TURN server etc)
2. When there is a sudden disconnect, prevent the user from sending any message until the connection is re-established.

My best guess is either one of the event handler below will do the trick, but I don't know which one, and don't know what are the differences between the two.
`onconnectionstatechange()`
`oniceconnectionstatechange()`

Answer (score 1):

oniceconnectionstatechange doesn't include the establishment of the DTLS handshake on top of the ice connection.

Use onconnectionstatechange to detect when the connection is fully established and also to detect disconnections.